# Recovering netbeans.conf file on Windows 10

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, configuration, ide

I downloaded a fresh copy of Netbeans and the fonts were a bit small so i was trying to edit the netbeans.conf file. I found the file and the way I opened it is by changing the extension to .txt which opened the file but when I wanted to save and close it it remained showing as a txt file even though I changes the xtension to .conf.

How can I restore my netbeans.conf file without having to uninstall and reinstall? I just want to learn how to do it the right way.

Thank you

Comment: open in notepad and press "save as" set filename  to "netbeans.conf" exactly same with braces around it.

Comment: Thank you sir, that did it.